# How to wire a phocos any-grid inverter 220 v 60 HZ with two wires to a water pump 220 with 3 wires (split 220 v)

Tags: wiring

How to wire a phocos any-grid inverter 220 v 60 HZ with two wires (European style) with one hot wire 220 v and another ground, to a water pump 220 v with 3 wires (split 220 v,  two 110 v hot wires and ground) US style.

Phocos ANY-GRID HYBRID INVERTER Charger PSW-H (5 KW) 48 v batteries, 220 volts output

Answer (score 1):

If the pump has two hot wires and a safety ground, but no Neutral, you should be able to connect it directly to the 220 V inverter 220 V and Ground output terminals.

Comment: How shall I connect the wires? The pump has three wires, two black (each accepting 110 v, and one green (ground). While the output of the inverter has only two wires, one hot 220 v and the other (neutral?).

Comment: The green wire is the safety ground - it will be connected to the frame of the motor and does not normally carry any current.  Just connect the two black wires to the two output wires of the inverter.